# Redirect URLs with br tag in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Sometimes a br tag is inserted into our urls when they're automatically linked from other websites. It triggers a 404 page. I want to remove that tag. For example, it looks like this:

```
http://www.healthyeatingstartshere.com/moti<br />vation/healthy-eating-routine
```

This is what I have so far to fix it, but no dice:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)<br%20/>(.*)$ http://www.healthyeatingstartshere.com/$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks very much, Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the space with a backslash

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)<br\ />(.*)$ http://www.healthyeatingstartshere.com/$1$2 [L,R=301]
```